# Manually fail a Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am calling an [interactor](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor-rails) inside a worker and I want the Sidekiq job to fail if the interactor fails.

```
def perform(id)
    result = RandomInteractor.call(id: id)

    # catch and respond to result.failure?
  end
```

Right now, this will display the job as **completed** rather than **failed**.

Comment: Sidekiq will retry failed jobs by default, do you want to retry in this case?

Comment: I don't want to retry (I also placed `sidekiq_options retry: false` for this) but I do want to catch the error message

Comment: Are you getting any exception or failure flag when `Interactor#call` method  fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used interactor gem before but based on your question, this should work:

```
def perform(id)
    result = RandomInteractor.call(id: id)
    raise StandardError if result.failure?
end
```

Since you have setup to not retry failed jobs, this should be marked as Failed as soon as the exception is raised.

Comment: Thank you! I used this along with the Sidekiq Status Gem (https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) so that I could show the error message (`store(message: result.errors)`)